# Please explain me this regex

Tags: regex

I have been studying regex for a few days specially with lookarounds. I cannot understand this regex that doesnot match sentence consisting of "bar".

```
^(?!.*bar).*$
```

I cannot understand why `.*bar` is used. If someone could give me a good explanation that would help me a lot.Thanks....

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/lF1gI7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A negative lookahead is something which fails the entire match if ever what's inside it is matched.

So, if at the point specified (in your example, `^` specifies at the start of the line) the pattern inside the lookahead matches, the whole match fails.

Let's see, you have `.*bar`. If `.*bar` matches, the whole regex fails.

When does `.*bar` match? The answer would be that it matches whenever there's `bar` in the line:

```
bar
foo bar
foo bar baz
```

Let's say that there wasn't any `.*`. You would thus have `bar` in the negative lookahead. If `bar` only matches, then the whole match fails. Now, remember that this check is at the beginning.

```
bar
foo bar
foo bar baz
```

The first line is the only one what will match `bar` at the beginning. So `^(?!bar).*$` will only prevent a match at the beginning of a line, but `^(?!.*bar).*$` will prevent a match anywhere in the line if there is `bar`.

Hopefully, that makes it a bit clearer :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: fixed the example

```
(?!.*bar)
```

Is a negative lookahead meaning that it checks to make sure that .*bar isn't in the line.

Here is an example of how to use negative lookaheads ([See it in action](http://regex101.com/r/gU8aB5)):

```
(?!GBP).*\d{3}.*
```

This makes sure to match three digit numbers, only when they are not preceded by the term 'GBP'

Comment: You don't need the neg lookahead in your example... [link](http://regex101.com/r/uS1mK9)

Comment: Well, I'm sure you realised when trying out that the negative lookahead still matches if you don't have the anchor, yes? In your example, the better solution would be two negative lookbehinds and a word boundary to prevent matching more than 3 numbers: [link](http://regex101.com/r/lD6zY1)

Comment: Thanks Jerry, that is a great example.

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**

```
^(?!.*bar).*$
```

**[Source](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5E%28?!.%2abar%29.%2a%24):**

```
  
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    bar                      'bar'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```